# How to use CardView in React-native while rendering data?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I get some JSON array from API calling and I want to show them in a list using CardView. But while I am using the CardView tag, it keeps rendering but not showing the data in card. There is nothing wrong with fetching the data as I logged them in console and printed the values.
If, I remove the cardView tag then it works well.

I installed the CardView component using following command-

**npm install react-native-cardview --save**

I took help from the site- 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cardview

But it is not working as it is mentioned. So, here, I have provided the code-

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, ToastAndroid, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import {Icon, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left} from 'native-base';
import CustomHeader from './CustomHeader';

import CardView from 'react-native-cardview';

let jwt=''
 class NoteMeHome extends React.Component {

   state = {
      getValue: '',
      dataSource:[],
      isLoading: true
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then(value => {
      const url = 'my url';
     return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'token': 'abc',
        'jwt': value
      })
    })
     .then((response)=> response.json() )
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log('####:'+responseJson[0].title)
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson,
        isLoading: false,
        getValue: value

      })
    })
    .catch((Error) => {
      console.log(Error)
    })

    }

    )}


  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: "Home",
    headerLeft: <Icon name="ios-menu" style={{paddingLeft:10}}
    onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}/>,

    drawerIcon: 

    <Image source={{uri: 'https://png.icons8.com/message/ultraviolet/50/3498db'}}
            style={styles.icon}
    />
  })



  render() {
    const { getValue } = this.state;

    return(
      this.state.isLoading
      ?
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#330066" animating/>
      </View>
      :
      <Container>
        <CustomHeader
          title="Home"
          drawerOpen={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
        />

        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index+""}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          />
        </View>


      </Container>
    )
  }

  renderSeparator = ()=> {
    return (
      <View style={{height:1, width:'100%', backgroundColor:'black'}}>

      </View>
    )
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return(

           <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}
            onPress= {() => ToastAndroid.show(item.title, ToastAndroid.SHORT)}
          >

  <CardView
          cardElevation={3}
          cardMaxElevation={2}
          cornerRadius={5}
     paddingBottom={10}

     style={{justifyContent:'center',margin:2,backgroundColor:'white'}}

    // height='auto' or you can also specify the height in number  as per requirement
          >
       <View style={{padding:10}}>


     <Image style={{width:80, height:80, margin:5}}
               source={{uri: 'https://png.icons8.com/message/ultraviolet/50/3498db'}}
        />
        <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', marginLeft:5}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:'green', marginBottom:10}}>
              {item.category}
            </Text>

            <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:'red', marginBottom:10}}>
              {item.title}
            </Text>
        </View>

        </View>
 </CardView>


      </TouchableOpacity>

    )
  }


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon:{
    height: 24,
    width: 24
  },
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
  }
})
export default NoteMeHome;
```

So, it would be very nice if someone helps me to know how I can show the item lists in a cardView.